# Add Role Level Hierarchy in Party/Organization Database Model

Tags: roles

I have implemented a data model based on Party Organisation Data model
It works fine with every aspects .Each representation of entity is as a party 
and Major party types are

1. Person
2. Organisation

In party type Person I can add multiple person types like

1. Super User
2. Organisational Administrator
3. Manager
4. User

Now I have to add a role based settings for the person .My system consists of Multiple organisations and persons are different in different organisation. Super user can control all person,Organisation.

Persons under Super User depends on the Organisation

[image]

Refer my basic data model in the above picture

I need to implement different permission levels in this system.Also it must have an ability to add more person levels and their permissions

One of my solution

Party is available with these major party types

Organization which consists of tenants
Person ( Which consist of Super User, Tenant Admin, Tenant Manager, Tenant Executives etc 
and more

Relationship between Party defined in party model is by party_relation and it is specified in party_relation_type ( Party Level Relationship )

For example 
      Main Organization to Tenant Organization
     Tenant  Organization to  Tenants

How to arrange different Person Levels under different tenants

Person levels are maintained by hierarchy in Person type 
Add Common column Hierarchy which consist of ancestor_id,Parent_id,hierarchy_level,hierarchy_path to Person_type
Introduce a person_type_relation   ( Person Level Relationship )

For example
     Tenant Admin to Tenant Manager
     Tenant Manager to Tenant Executive

Introduce a Permission Mechanism table , separate tables for person_relation_type and person_relation_type_permissions. 
This describes which permissions for a particular relation